# What is wrong with my HttpURLConnection request?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, odata

I am trying to call a REST API with a PUT Request but I am receiving a 400 Error Code (Bad Request).  Can someone spot what I may be doing wrong?

I have successfully called this API with a REST Client, here are the headers and body used:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH8I5.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENSVT.jpg

```
    String credentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("wcadmin:wcadmin").getBytes());
    URL url = new URL(getURL());
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);

    //Set Headers
    String fileUrl = "c:\\0000000050.xml";
    File fileToUpload = new File(fileUrl);
    long length = fileToUpload.length();
    String FORM_DATA_BOUNDARY = "------FormBoundary" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    connection.setRequestProperty("csrf_nonce", getNonceValue());
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + FORM_DATA_BOUNDARY);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Long.toString(length));

    //Setup Request Body Writer
    OutputStream requestBodyOutputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter requestBodyWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(requestBodyOutputStream));

    //Write Body
    requestBodyWriter.write("\r\n\r\n");
    requestBodyWriter.write(FORM_DATA_BOUNDARY);
    requestBodyWriter.write("\r\n");
    requestBodyWriter.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fileUrl + "\"");
    requestBodyWriter.write("\r\n");
    requestBodyWriter.write("Content-Type: text/xml");
    requestBodyWriter.write("\r\n\r\n");
    requestBodyWriter.flush();

    FileInputStream uploadFileStream = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
    while ((bytesRead = uploadFileStream.read(dataBuffer)) != -1) {
        requestBodyOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    requestBodyOutputStream.flush();

    requestBodyWriter.write("\r\n");
    requestBodyWriter.write(FORM_DATA_BOUNDARY);
    requestBodyWriter.flush();

    //Close the streams
    requestBodyOutputStream.close();
    requestBodyWriter.close();
    uploadFileStream.close();

    //Read Response
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        if (responseReader != null) {
            while ((inputLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(inputLine);
            }
            responseReader.close();
        }
    }

    connection.disconnect();
```

Error 400 Bad Request response received

Answer (score 0):

First and most important:  you cannot write to both an OutputStream, and a OutputStreamWriter which wraps that same OutputStream.  They will conflict with each other.

Do not use OutputStreamWriter at all;  instead, convert text to bytes yourself:

```
OutputStream requestBodyOutputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

requestBodyOutputStream.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
requestBodyOutputStream.write(FORM_DATA_BOUNDARY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
// etc.
```

Second, you are converting between bytes and strings using the system’s default charset, which means exactly what gets written depends on the system where the code is running.  Don’t call String.getBytes without specifying an explicit Charset.  Usually `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is what you want.

Similarly, you need to pass a Charset to your InputStreamReader creation (although this isn’t the cause of your problem, since you aren’t getting a valid response at the moment).  Don’t assume a charset;  use the `charset` MIME type parameter from the response’s [Content-Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29) header.  If you’re using a version of Java older than 11, you can parse the Content-Type value with the [javax.activation.MimeType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/activation/MimeType.html) class, but be aware that the javax.activation package has been removed from Java SE as of Java 11.  For Java 11 and later, [Java Activation can be downloaded](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index-135046.html) as a stand-alone library.  Another option is to use the JavaMail library, specifically its [ContentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/ContentType.html) class, for parsing.

Third, the Content-Length header *inside* the body part (between the boundaries) should use the file’s length as a Content-Length.  The Content-Length of the *entire request body* must be the length of everything you’ve written:  the boundaries, the body part headers, and the file content.

The good news is, I think (though I’m not positive) that URLConnection will set the request’s overall Content-Length automatically, based on the bytes you write, so you probably don’t need to compute the length yourself;  you can simply refrain from setting "Content-Length" at all.

When you do pass a correct request, you will find that you are dropping the newlines in the response.  If the response is supposed to be human-readable text, those newlines are likely to matter.  If you’re using Java 10 or later, you can use [Reader.transferTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#transferTo%28java.io.Writer%29) with a StringWriter:

```
StringWriter responseBody = new StringWriter();
responseReader.transferTo(responseBody);
String content = responseBody.toString();
```

If you’re using a version of Java older than 10:

- `new BufferedReader` *cannot* return null, so checking for null is pointless.  In Java, the `new` operator always, no matter what, returns a new object (unless an exception is thrown, in which case `new` doesn’t return at all).
- You should use StringBuilder, not StringBuffer.  They are identical except that StringBuffer is an older class that provides thread safety for every method, creating unnecessary overhead for nearly all use cases.

You are copying your file into the request without any buffering, which is going to be slow and inefficient.  Consider using `Files.copy(fileToUpload.toPath(), requestBodyOutputStream)` instead.